# Symfony 5.4 environmental variables in services.yaml::parameters

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5

Recently I decided to use Symfony 5.4 container in one of the projects to provide some comprehensive DI. It works well as usual, until I tried to use some env vars in `services.yaml::parameters` section.

Docs state that to bind to an env var I should

```yaml
# services.yaml
parameters:
  my_var: '%env(SOME_ENV_VAR)%'
```

and it will be resolved from an env var on first call. Okay. I did it this way and here what I get:

```php
echo $container->getParameter('my_var');
// env_b057c2b619f37f36_SOME_ENV_VAR_222ed306d0932595cbdeada438ccbb2a
```

I do see `SOME_ENV_VAR` in both `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV`. I also tried `Dotenv` component to be sure I'm not missing something, but vainly. Any env var turns into this sort of  `env_{hash}_{VAR_NAME}_{hash}` pattern.

I'm not using complete Symfony installation, just some spare components. What I'm missing? Should I manually populate each env var on container build stage?

---

Container is instantiated as follows:

```php
// $_ENV and $_SERVER already contain `SOME_ENV_VAR` here

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// `use` statements go here

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

$loader = new YamlFileLoader(
  $containerBuilder,
  new FileLocator(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [__DIR__, 'config']))
);

$loader->load('services.yaml');

$containerBuilder->compile();

$container = $containerBuilder;

$my_var = $container->getParameter('SOME_ENV_VAR');

echo $my_var;
```

Comment: The PHP runtime does not automatically read env variables.  You can confirm this with a simple var_dump($_ENV);  It is up to you to set the values.  Add `putenv('SOME_ENV_VAR','value');` before compiling the container and the error should go away.  You should also be able to read variables from a .env file using the Dotenv component.  Might want to revisit what you tried.

Comment: @yivi I do agree and I tried to pass that param as an arg to a service and value is the same. I'm using container after `->compile()`.

Comment: Ok, I would still need to see more to be able to know what's going on. The above code and configuration are not enough to be able to reliably reproduce the issue and give you a solution.

Comment: @Cerad Env vars are in tact. They do exist in system env also I do see the both in `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` before and after container compilation as I stated in my question before, thats why I'm wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your updated snippet, you need to use:

```
$container->compile(true); // false is the default
```

The argument is called resolveEnvPlaceholders.  I remember it catching me some time ago.

Still find it a bit puzzling that you have $_ENV set but I'll take your word for it.

This is an old test case I dug up that still works:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class Service 
{
  public function __construct(string $dsn)
  {
    echo $dsn . "\n";
  }
}
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->autowire(Service::class,Service::class)->setPublic(true)
    ->setArguments([
        '%env(DSN)%'
  ]);
$container->setParameter('my_var','%env(DSN)%');

putenv('DSN=dsn_value');
$container->compile(true);

$service = $container->get(Service::class);

echo $container->getParameter('my_var') . "\n";
```

Comment: OMG. How embarassing. Many thanks! Thats a bit odd that I couldn't find it mentioned somewhere regarding `$resolveEnvPlaceholders` when written about env vars resolution, but maybe I missed it somewhere completely.

Comment: Not sure it is documented except for the argument name.  Symfony component documentation is often a bit lacking.  Within the framework the compiled container is written into a file and then loaded back in for each request.  In that scenario you want to use the current env values instead of the values at compile time.  So I guess that it why it defaults to false.

Comment: Yes, with cached container env vars are cached as well (_when `true`_) and for changing env vars you should recompile the container. Something to keep in mind in such case.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `ContainerBuilder::compile()` is:

```
public function compile(bool $resolveEnvPlaceholders = false)
```

If you do not pass it `true`, it won't resolve the environment variables' placeholders.

Additionally, there is an issue with your example.

You are calling:

```
$my_var = $container->getParameter('SOME_ENV_VAR');
```

But `SOME_ENV_VAR` is not a container parameter, but an environment variable. The correct call would be:

```
$my_var = $container->getParameter('my_var');
```

The whole thing would be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

$loader = new YamlFileLoader(
    $containerBuilder,
    new FileLocator(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [__DIR__, 'config']))
);

$loader->load(__DIR__ . '/services.yaml');

$containerBuilder->compile(true);

$container = $containerBuilder;
$my_var    = $container->getParameter('my_var');

echo $my_var;
```

Comment: Thank you. I never actually read the signature of `compile()` until now and it seems to be nowhere mentioned in docs that for resolving env vars it should be `true`. Thank you for lightning fast reaction and participation! Appreciate!